# SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask throws "Specified method is not supported"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I'm trying to call AlterTask on a newly created Sharepoint task to add extended properties to my task, and a NotSupportedException is thrown.

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newly created task is actually a SharePoint ListItem.   ExtendedProperties is specifically a Workflow Task property.

As per the MSDN documentation:

```
The content type of the item passed to the task parameter is not derived from the WorkflowTask content type.
```

This means that Content Type of the SPListItem that represents your new Task must be set to "Workflow Task" before the AlterTask method can be called on it:

```
    Dim selectedTaskList As SPList = web.Lists(taskListName)

    ' Create a new task item
    Dim newTask As SPListItem = selectedTaskList.Items.Add()

   ' Turn the new task item into a Workflow Task
    Dim newTaskContentType As Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType = web.AvailableContentTypes("Workflow Task")
    newTask("ContentTypeId") = newTaskContentType.Id

   ' Now the AlterTask method will work.  (assume you've alreade declared a hashtable of properties to set)
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(newTask, myHashTable, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim IntItemID As Integer
    Dim siteId As Guid = SPContext.Current.Site.ID
    Dim webId As Guid = SPContext.Current.Web.ID
    Using objSpSite As New SPSite(siteId)
        Using objSpWeb As SPWeb = objSpSite.OpenWeb(webId)

            If Not Page.Request.QueryString("ItemID") Is Nothing And Page.Request.QueryString("ItemID") <> "" Then
                IntItemID = CInt(Page.Request.QueryString.Item("ItemID").ToString)
                Panel1.Visible = False

                txtID.Text = IntItemID.ToString
                Dim objList As SPList = objSpWeb.Lists("RequestList")
                Dim objListItem As SPListItem = objList.Items.GetItemById(IntItemID)
                dtPermission.SelectedDate = objListItem("PermissionDate")
                dtTimeFrom.SelectedDate = objListItem("PermissionFromTime")
                dtTimeTo.SelectedDate = objListItem("PermissionToTime")
                cmbType.SelectedValue = objListItem("PermissionType")
                'dtCreated.SelectedDate = objListItem("")

            Else
                IntItemID = 0
                txtID.Text = "New"
                dtCreated.SelectedDate = Today
                txtCreatedBy.Text = objSpWeb.CurrentUser.Name
                Dim objServiceContext As SPServiceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(objSpSite)
                Dim objUserProfileManager As New UserProfileManager(objServiceContext)

                Dim objUserProfile As UserProfile
                Dim strUserAccount As String
                strUserAccount = objSpWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName.Replace("i:0#.w|", "")
                If objUserProfileManager.UserExists(strUserAccount) Then
                    objUserProfile = objUserProfileManager.GetUserProfile(strUserAccount)
                    Try
                        txtManager.Text = objUserProfile.GetManager.AccountName
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        txtManager.Text = ex.Message
                    End Try

                End If


                Panel2.Visible = False

            End If

        End Using
    End Using


End Sub

Protected Sub cmdSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click
    Dim siteId As Guid = SPContext.Current.Site.ID
    Dim webId As Guid = SPContext.Current.Web.ID

    Using objSpSite As New SPSite(siteId)
        Using objSpWeb As SPWeb = objSpSite.OpenWeb(webId)
            objSpWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = True
            Dim list As SPList = objSpWeb.Lists("RequestList")
            Dim item As SPListItem = list.Items.Add()
            item("PermissionDate") = dtPermission.SelectedDate
            item("PermissionFromTime") = dtTimeFrom.SelectedDate
            item("PermissionToTime") = dtTimeTo.SelectedDate
            item("PermissionType") = cmbType.SelectedValue
            item("PermissionApprover1") = txtManager.Text

            item.Update()
            list.Update()
            objSpWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = False
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdApprove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdApprove.Click
    Dim siteId As Guid = SPContext.Current.Site.ID
    Dim webId As Guid = SPContext.Current.Web.ID
    Using objSpSite As New SPSite(siteId)
        Using objSpWeb As SPWeb = objSpSite.OpenWeb(webId)
            Dim objList As SPList = objSpWeb.Lists("RequestList")
            Dim objListItem As SPListItem = objList.Items.GetItemById(CInt(txtID.Text))

            Dim objWFTask As SPWorkflowTask = objListItem.Tasks(0)

            If objWFTask Is Nothing Then
                ' no matching task
                Return
            End If

            ' alter the task
            Dim ht As New Hashtable()

            ht("Status") = "Complete"
            ht("PercentComplete") = 1.0F

            SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(TryCast(objWFTask, SPListItem), ht, True)
        End Using
    End Using
```